# Error on create view with cast numeric as decimal on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, view, casting, decimal, numeric

Good morning everyone!

I currently work with postgresql. Well, I need to create views where the numeric columns stay rounded 15.3 but I'm encountering a problem I could not understand.

The select work:

```
select cast(15.2547 as decimal(15,3)) as quantidade_medida_estatistica
```

The view not working:

```
create or replace view teste as select cast(15.2547 as decimal(15,3)) as quantidade_medida_estatistica
```

Error:

> ERROR: can not change the data type of column view "quantidade_medida_estatistica" of numeric (15,4) to numeric (15,3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known "bug" in Postgres, which you can read about [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/200709040742.l847gxZ9025050%40wwwmaster.postgresql.org#200709040742.l847gxZ9025050@wwwmaster.postgresql.org).

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` is not exactly the same as dropping the view and re-creating it.  In this case the existing columns in the view need to be the same, as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html):

> `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` is similar, but if a view of the same name
>   already exists, it is replaced. **The new query must generate the same
>   columns that were generated by the existing view query** (that is, the
>   same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but
>   it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations
>   giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

You can do what you want by dropping and re-creating the view.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explicitly state that, but I guess the view already exists - at least the error message indicates that.

Unfortunately you can't change the data types of the columns of an existing view when using `create or replace`.

You need to drop and create the view:

```
drop view teste;
create view teste 
as 
select cast(15.2547 as decimal(15,3)) as quantidade_medida_estatistica;
```